# Why is regex not returning any matches?

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to use regexes to pull certain substrings from the text in the body of an outlook email.

Here is the function with the regex that I'm trying to use:

```
def EventDescription(emailbody):
    regex = r'\d\d:\d\d\sDescription: (.*?)\s(?:_)'
    substring = re.findall(regex, emailbody, re.DOTALL)
    # return the matches
    return substring
```

Here is the raw string I'm trying to perform the regex on:

```
***External Sender - This email is from an external sender.*** 
     
Date/Time Start:     
2021-12-25 08:38     
Anticipated Date/Time Restored:  
2021-12-25 16:21     
Duration:    
7.72     
Outage Type:     
Forced Outage (FO)   
Capacity De-Rate:    
0.00     
Maximo Work Orders:  
Work Order #:NA00360131, Description: ALO1: ALO1_B002_P008.Inv016 - Inverter 16 is derating due to a broken tracking motor.  

Created On: 2021-12-26 09:06
Description: Updated!
Inverter 16 is restored by site tech.
________________________________________

     
Date/Time Start:     
2021-12-25 09:53     
Anticipated Date/Time Restored:  
2021-12-27 16:00     
Duration:    
54.12    
Outage Type:     
Forced Outage (FO)   
Capacity De-Rate:    
0.85     
Maximo Work Orders:  
Work Order #:NA00360131, Description: ALO1: ALO1_B002_P008.Inv016 - Inverter 16 is derating due to a broken tracking motor.  

Created On: 2021-12-25 13:58
Description: 
Updated ETR.
________________________________________

     
Date/Time Start:     
2021-12-25 09:53     
Anticipated Date/Time Restored:  
2021-12-25 16:00     
Duration:    
6.12     
Outage Type:     
Forced Outage (FO)   
Capacity De-Rate:    
0.85     
Maximo Work Orders:  
Work Order #:NA00360131, Description: ALO1: ALO1_B002_P008.Inv016 - Inverter 16 is derating due to a broken tracking motor.  

Created On: 2021-12-25 09:54
Description: 
Inverter 16 tripped offline. No fault code available in FleetCon or SCADA. Site personnel informed.
________________________________________
```

But when I try to pull one of the entries from the list "substring" I get a "IndexError: list index out of range" error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your pattern does not match, because in the example text there is no match for `\s_`

Comment: Could you place the place the text literal inside a codeblock (without syntax highlighting aka `\`\`\` text`)? I have the feeling that the underscore dividers placed in the question source are part of the text. Yet they are currently parsed by the markdown engine, giving us the feeling that you are trying to parse 3 separate strings instead of 1 big string.

Comment: I believe I've fixed my original post to better show the raw string (let me know if otherwise) but you're correct. When I copy/paste the email body into a text editor the dividers show up as underscores, which is why I included those as part of my original regex to differentiate the 3 separate instances I'm trying to match.

Comment: @RandomUser27 Your pattern seems to work right? See https://ideone.com/hgCRDP

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is pretty complicated and does not return any matches. You should try this one:

```
regex = r'\d\d:\d\d\sDescription: (.*)'
```

It simply matches the whole string after `Description:` . With your example string, it returns all matches you requested.

**EDIT:** You also have to remove an argument from `findall` for it to work. The `re.DOTALL` does not stop the match at a new line. With following code you should receive the desired output:

```
def EventDescription(emailbody):
    regex = r'\d\d:\d\d\sDescription: (.*)'
    substring = re.findall(regex, emailbody)
    # return the matches
    return substring
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The concern with the suggestion above is that I need it to only return the string after 'Description:' up until the next divider just before the 'Date/Time Start:' text. It should return 3 matches in the example string since there are 3 instances of the 'Description' text that's preceded by the timestamp. The divider appears to read as underscores when I copy the email body into a text editor, which is why my original regex had the '(?:_)' at the end.

Comment: You are right. I only tested the regex and not your code. You used a flag that is not necessary. Removing it results in your desired output. I added the new function in the answer.

Comment: I edited my original post to better show the raw string, but the issue with removing the DOTALL is there are some instances where the substring I'm trying to return spans multiple lines. For example, the first match should include "Update!" as well as "Inverter 16 is restored by site tech." on the following line.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Description:\s(.*?)_{40,}
```

This way we're matching everything between Description and the line of underscores. Note you still need to use DOTALL mode.

https://regex101.com/r/qoiSwl/1

I added `End of Event \n\n\n` just to highlight where each match starts and ends, since with the newlines it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
\d{2}:\d{2}\s+Description:\s*(.*?)\s+_
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ibhQj9/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Description:             'Description:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
```